# Excel - sorting data by columns with matching data with messed up order

Tags: excel, sorting, grouping

I have a table with following structure:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
StringA ValueA  StringB ValueB
StringB ValueC  StringA ValueD
```

Every string in ColumnA is unique and has equivalent in ColumnC, but the order is messed up.
What I want to achieve is a table like this:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
StringA ValueA  ValueB
```

Any tips? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for VLOOKUP function

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;$B$1:$C$2;2;0)
```